# Strange edition field in BibTeX handling

Tags: bibtex

I've the following strange edition for a document.

```
@Book{howell15:_ode,
  language =     {english},
  author =   {Howell, Kenneth B.},
  title =    {Ordinary Differential Equations:
              An Introduction to the Fundamentals},
  publisher =    {Hayden-McNeil Publising},
  year =     2015,
  edition =  {2014--2015},
  where =    {http://howellkb.uah.edu/DEtext}
}
```

With `babelbib` and `cite` packages, and `babplain-fl`, I get output like (transcribed from the PDF):

> [404] Kenneth B. Howell, *Ordinary Differential Equations: An Introduction to the Fundamentals*. Hayden-McNeil Publishing, --20152014-2015 edition, 2015.

Note the strange edition formatting, it is not a mistake in the .bib file. It should come out somewhat like "2014-2015 edition".

Any suggestion on how to get a somewhat reasonable output? As the reference number shows, this is in an extensive set of entries, so any tweaking of the bibliography style to "fix" the handling of the edition tag generally (except for such situations) is out of the question. Placing `{}` around the string doesn't help.

I'm using texlive, as it comes with Fedora 22 (current versions of both).

An MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[czech, english, german, french, latin, spanish, romanian]
              {article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib, cite}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliographystyle{babplain-fl}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding mwe.bib file follows:

```
  @Book{howell15:_ode,
  language =     {english},
  author =   {Howell, Kenneth B.},
  title =    {Ordinary Differential Equations:
          An Introduction to the Fundamentals},
  publisher =    {Hayden-McNeil Publising},
  year =     2015,
  edition =  {{2014--2015}},
  where =    {http://howellkb.uah.edu/DEtext}
}
```

Comment: @Mico, the main language is Spanish. The bibliography contains a host of entries in assorted languages.

Comment: The main document language in your example is Romanian - not Spanish.

Comment: @cfr, note the \selectlanguage{spanish}.

Comment: The main document language is still Romanian - not Spanish. I'm not saying that should be a problem. I'm just saying that it is Romanian as far as `babel` is concerned. I think the problem with edition is that you are not really meant to use a value like a date range. It expects an ordinal e.g. usually editions are e.g. 'second' or 'third'. Admittedly sometimes you get e.g. 'new' or 'revised' or whatever. But why repeat date information in the edition?

Comment: @cfr, ask the people who called it this. It is more or less a bound version of a set of web pages. Check the link in the where tag. And my manuals say \selectlanguage{A} selects that as the language for the text.

Comment: If you are sure it needs to be like that, fake it. It doesn't have to go in the `edition` field. Or consider using Biblatex/Biber which offers a lot more flexibility and control.

Comment: If I remove the `czech` language option and change the edition field to `edition =  {2014--2015}` (note: single, not double, braces), the problem disappears. Incidentally, does your document contain passages in seven different languages, including Czech?

Comment: Your manuals are wrong. If you look at the `.log`, you'll see that `babelbib`'s "fallback language" is Romanian.  That is because you load that langauge last for `babel`.  This is clearly explained in the `babel` manual in section 1 of part 1. `\selectlanguage` is -- sort of -- a "local" command.

Comment: @mico, biber is a no go. I don't want to have to rewrite my 800+ entry .bib files and the many documents depending on them. And no, my document doesn't have all those languages, just references documents written/published in all of them, I need to load the languages to get babel to handle the references.

Comment: @vonbrand - I'm confused: AFAICT, I didn't say anything related to biber.

Comment: @Mico, sorry for confusing your comment with cfr's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. The problem (as @Mico noted) is with the czech language. The following kludge fakes the edition:

```
@Preamble{"\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{}"}

@Book{howell15:_ode,
  language =     {english},
  author =   {Howell, Kenneth B.},
  title =    {Ordinary Differential Equations:
          An Introduction to the Fundamentals},
  publisher =    {Hayden-McNeil Publising},
  year =     {\noopsort{2015}2014--2015 edition, 2015},
  where =    {http://howellkb.uah.edu/DEtext}
}
```

The \noopsort{} is to get the right date order, if required someday.